# How to create a dynamic Infopath form?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

i have a webpart that creates a list dynamically.Now i want to create a infopath form for that list dynamically with the columns of that list only, so that when a user clicks add a document that new infopath should open.

So, in a nutshell, my webpart creates a list with user specified columns and its infopath(which is it's default infopath).

i am using sharepoint 2010,infopath 2010,visul studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Deploy your InfoPath form as a site content type.
2. Modify the definition of the list created dynamically by your webpart so that the default content type for the list is the one created when you deployed your InfoPath form.

Then, when a user creates an item in the list, the default content type will be used and the InfoPath form will be displayed.